# How to mock event stop propagation in angular 6 for jasmine test case

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular6

How I can mock the event stop propagation in angular 6 for jasmine test case.

I am trying this -

```
 it('should call the onItemRightClick method', () => {

    event = jasmine.createSpyObj('event', ['preventDefault', 'stopPropagation']);
    expect(event.stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();
    component.onItemRightClick(params.event, params.ci);
    // expect(component.onItemRightClick).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
```

component code -

```
  onItemRightClick(event: MouseEvent, ci: CiWithKPIS) {
    console.debug('Open context panel for CI', ci.name);
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (!this.isSelected(ci)) {
      this._selectedItems = [ci];
      this.onSelectedCisChanged.emit(this._selectedItems);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.
It gives error - `TypeError: event.stopPropagation is not a function`
Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created spy on event object but passing different object in `component.onItemRightClick` method.
Use following line to resolve the problem:

```js
component.onItemRightClick(event, params.ci);
```